# Running gdalsrsinfo in subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, gdal

i have to run gdal commands from python in subprocesses.
The first command i tried is gdalsrsinfo.

```
self.proc = subprocess.Popen(['gdalsrsinfo', '-e', 'D:\tif\dop20c_33328_5650.tif'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
    while self.proc.poll() is None:
        output = self.proc.stdout.readline().strip()
        self.print_log.emit(output)
        if output.startswith(b'EPSG:'):
            epsg = output.rsplit(':',1)[1]
            self.print_log.emit(output)
```

Since the while loop is entered, the process starts. But the output variable is always empty. When i execute the same command in my shell, i get the correct output.
How can i get the same output from my shell in python? I also tries other gdal commands with the result. I don't get any output.

I'm working on Windows 10 with Python 3.7

By the way, the output of the command in my shell looks like this:

```
A:\>gdalsrsinfo -e D:\tif\dop20c_33328_5650.tif

EPSG:25833

PROJ.4 : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

OGC WKT2:2018 :
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 33N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["Europe - 12°E to 18°E and ETRS89 by country"],
        BBOX[46.4,12,84.01,18.01]],
    ID["EPSG",25833]]
```